# Problem with Infinispan Cache with OpenJDK 11.0.1 and WildFly 17.0.1.Final

Tags: java, wildfly, java-11, infinispan, wildfly-17

I need to create a simple infinispan cache on an application that uses Spring (no spring boot) and runs on WildFly 17.0.1.Final. I configured everything and wrote the Java code, but when I try to run it locally on my PC I get this error:
**23:12:52,476 WARN [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 96) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webAppConfig': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'java:jboss/infinispan/cache/session/user-data' is expected to be of type 'org.infinispan.Cache' but was actually of type 'org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.DefaultCache'**

However, on my colleague's PC it does not give an error and works normally.

**Java code:**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("aaa.bbb")
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:config.properties"})
@EnableScheduling
public class WebAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

        @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/cache/session/user-data") Cache<Object, Object> cache;

    @Bean    
    public Cache<Object, Object> cacheManager() throws Exception {        
        return cache;
    }
}
```

**POM:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
    <artifactId>infinispan-spring</artifactId>
    <version>8.2.4.Final</version>
</dependency>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>AAA</id>
        <properties>
            <application>NAMEEE</application>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifestEntries><Dependencies>org.infinispan, org.infinispan.commons, org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan export</Dependencies>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
            <finalName>NAMEEE</finalName>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

**WildFly standalone-full.xml:**

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:8.0">
    <cache-container name="web" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
        <local-cache name="passivation">
            <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
            <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
            <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
        </local-cache>
        <local-cache name="sso">
            <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
            <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
        </local-cache>
        <local-cache name="routing"/>
    </cache-container>
    <cache-container name="server" default-cache="default" module="org.wildfly.clustering.server">
        <local-cache name="default">
            <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
        </local-cache>
    </cache-container>
    <cache-container name="ejb" aliases="sfsb" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan">
        <local-cache name="passivation">
            <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
            <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
            <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
        </local-cache>
    </cache-container>
    <cache-container name="hibernate" module="org.infinispan.hibernate-cache">
        <local-cache name="entity">
            <object-memory size="10000"/>
            <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
        </local-cache>
        <local-cache name="local-query">
            <object-memory size="10000"/>
            <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
        </local-cache>
        <local-cache name="timestamps"/>
    </cache-container>
    <cache-container name="session" default-cache="user-data">
        <local-cache name="user-data">
            <locking concurrency-level="1000" isolation="READ_COMMITTED"/>
            <transaction locking="OPTIMISTIC" mode="NON_XA"/>
        </local-cache>
    </cache-container>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: Assuming that `org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.DefaultCache` implements `org.infinispan.Cache`, look at whether you have several instances of `org.infinispan.Cache` on your class path.